# importing axios client FROM server

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, client-server

I need to use axios both on my client and my server. I import it as

clientside: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>`

serverside: npm install

and it is fine.

**The question**: is there a way to import both from one source? (like you can import socket.io client as
`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
from installed sources)

axios is just an example. Can relate to anything used on cli and serv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Yes. If you've installed axios from npm then you'll have a *axios.min.js* file on your hard disk.

You just need to do *something* to give it a URL. The specifics of that will depend on your HTTP server. You might use [an Alias directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) if you were using Apache HTTPD or the [static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) if you were using Express.js.

You can't really compare to Socket.io though. The Socket.io module that is used server-side sets up a bunch of end points (because the socket communication takes place over HTTP) and one of those end points is designed to serve up the client-side code.